# Internet is slow with Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron-3543

Tags: wireless, dell

The Internet is working very slow on my laptop. When I am downloading something. it's speed going up to 700KB then it's going down to 0KB and it keeps doing this.

I tried to some solutions but none of them able to solve my problem example:  ignore IP6 etc.

I have no idea to which commands I should run to check the problem. please guide me. 
Thanks

```
sudo lshw -class network command output: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 01
       serial: 18:4f:32:fb:1c:d7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=172.16.0.178 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:aa100000-aa107fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:e6:e2:52:70:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:aa000000-aa000fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
```

Comment: Does the issue happen with a usb-wifi dongle too?

Comment: @dsSTORM I don't know. I never used USB Dongle in this pc.